# Rails 4 Devise and Carrierwave. User Avatar upload causes an untracable error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have devise working correctly in every aspect except for uploading an Avatar during signup or edit. If you sign up through facebook the FB profile is uploaded as an avatar (which does work). It is only broken when you try to upload yourself on signup or edit.

If you try to upload an avatar yourself, upon submit you are sent to /signup (exactly "signup", not "sign-up" or "sign_up") which throws a 404 and absolutely nothing happens in the logs (seriously - nothing - totally blank for that action).

If you do not try to add an avatar both the new & edit forms work fine.

Here is the code.

**registrations_controller.rb**

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
include ApplicationHelper

def create
  super
end

def new
  super
end

def edit
  super
end

protected

def update_resource(resource, params)
  resource.update_without_password(params)
end
```

end

**models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
devise :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:facebook]

acts_as_voter
mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
  user = User.where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first

  # The User was found in our database
  return user if user

  # Check if the User is already registered without Facebook
  user = User.where(email: auth.info.email).first

  return user if user

  # The User was not found and we need to create them
  User.create(real_name:     auth.extra.raw_info.name,
            provider: auth.provider,
            uid:      auth.uid,
            location: auth.info.location,
            language: auth.info.language,
            gender:   auth.extra.raw_info.gender,
            email:    auth.info.email,
            password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20],
            remote_avatar_url: auth.info.image)
  end


attr_accessor :login

def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
  conditions = warden_conditions.dup
  if login = conditions.delete(:login)
    where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) =      :value", {value: login.downcase}]).first
  else
    where(conditions).first
  end
end


devise authentication_keys: [:login]
end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
protect_from_forgery with: :exception

before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :real_name, :gender, :language, :location, :age, :avatar, :avatar_cache) }
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:login, :username, :email, :password, :remember_me) }
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :real_name, :gender, :language, :location, :age, :avatar, :avatar_cache, :remove_avatar) }
end


private

def require_user_signed_in
  unless user_signed_in?

  # If the user came from a page, we can send them back.  Otherwise, send
  # them to the root path.
  if request.env['HTTP_REFERER']
    fallback_redirect = :back
  elsif defined?(root_path)
    fallback_redirect = root_path
  else
    fallback_redirect = "/"
  end

  redirect_to fallback_redirect, flash: {error: "You must be signed in to view this page."}
end
end

end
```

**routes**

```
root 'posts#index'

devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: "users/registrations", sessions: "users/sessions", passwords: "users/passwords", omniauth_callbacks: "users/omniauth_callbacks"}, skip: [:sessions, :registrations] 

devise_scope :user do
  get    "login"   => "users/sessions#new",         as: :new_user_session
  post   "login"   => "users/sessions#create",      as: :user_session
  delete "signout" => "users/sessions#destroy",     as: :destroy_user_session

  get    "signup"  => "users/registrations#new",    as: :new_user_registration
  post   "signup"  => "users/registrations#create", as: :user_registration
  put    "signup"  => "users/registrations#update", as: :update_user_registration
  get    "account" => "users/registrations#edit",   as: :edit_user_registration
end
```

**/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>


<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :username, class: "control-label col-md-4" %>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <%= f.text_field :username, class: "text-field form-control", html: {spellcheck: "false"} %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :avatar, class: "control-label col-md-4" %>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :email, class: "control-label col-md-4" %>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <%= f.email_field :email, class: "text-field form-control", html: {spellcheck: "false"} %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :password, class: "control-label col-md-4" %>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <%= f.password_field :password, class: "text-field form-control", html: {autocomplete: "off"} %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Password Confirmation", class: "control-label col-md-4" %>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "text-field form-control", html: {autocomplete: "off"} %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-8">
    <%= f.submit "Sign Up", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb**
(this is really long so I've only included the relevant parts here

```
  <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>

<div class="form-group">
                        <strong>Existing Avatar</strong><BR>
                        <% if current_user.avatar.url.present? %>
                        <%= image_tag @current_user.avatar_url(:large).to_s  %>
                        <%= f.label :remove_avatar do %>
                          <%= f.check_box :remove_avatar, class: 'form-control'  %>
                        <% end %>
                      <% end %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <%= f.label :avatar, class: "control-label col-md-4" %>
                        <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
                        <%= f.hidden_field :avatar_cache %>
                    </div>
<div class="form-actions">
                    <%= f.submit 'Update', :class => 'button right' %>

                  </div>
```

**/uploaders/avatar_uploader.rb**

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
include CarrierWave::RMagick
storage :file

def store_dir
  "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end

def cache_dir
  "/tmp/avatarTmp"
end


process :scale => [200, 300]


version :tiny do
  process :resize_to_fit => [20, 20]
end

version :thumb do
  process :resize_to_fit => [50, 50]
end

version :large do
  process :resize_to_fit => [200, 200]
end

def extension_white_list
  %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
end

def filename
  "avatar.jpg" if original_filename
end
```

end

Comment: Maybe because you are wrongly submitting the ```form```. As per your ```devise_scope``` the form should be submitting to ```user_registration_path``` and not ```registration_path```.  Which is ```/users/signup```.

Comment: That was close. Thanks. It was actually edit_registration_path but you put me on the correct area so thanks. Now Im faced with an issue that if the image is large it wont be uploaded and it goest to /account as a 404 (again with nothing in the logs - just like before). any ideas? Its really strange. The page exists yet I get a 404 when I try to u/l a large image.